# Running cordova -v using PHP’s shell_exec()

Tags: php, linux, cordova, ubuntu

Has anyone managed to successfully get PHP's `shell_exec()` to successfully run an Cordova-CLI command? Essentially, when I run the following:

```php
<?php
    try {
        putenv('PATH='. getenv('PATH') .':/usr/local/bin');
        exec('cordova -v 2>&1', $output);
        print_r($output);
    }
    catch(Exception $ex) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($ex);
    }
?>
```

I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => path.js:8
    [1] =>     throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' +
    [2] =>     ^
    [3] => 
    [4] => TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    [5] =>     at assertPath (path.js:8:11)
    [6] =>     at Object.posix.join (path.js:479:5)
    [7] =>     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/util.js:35:31)
    [8] =>     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    [9] =>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    [10] =>     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    [11] =>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    [12] =>     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    [13] =>     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    [14] =>     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/cordova.js:21:20)
)
```

It just show the same error when I try to use php `shell_exec` to run Cordova. For testing I just print out the version of Cordova. But the error persist. When I use the terminal on Ubuntu, Cordova runs just fine but it doesn't run on PHP application.

Comment: Hi Did you get the solution ? I am getting same error